# Como ordenar um array com php

Tags: php

Bom tenho uma variável `$produtos`que recebe o seguinte array:

```
 array (size=6)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'id' => string '107' (length=3)
          'nome' => string 'LAREIRA PEQ.' (length=12)
          'qtd' => float 43
          'total' => float 64500
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'id' => string '108' (length=3)
          'nome' => string 'CHORAQUERIA PEQ.' (length=16)
          'qtd' => float 60
          'total' => float 48000
      2 => 
        array (size=4)
          'id' => string '109' (length=3)
          'nome' => string 'JOGO DE FACAS' (length=13)
          'qtd' => float 90
          'total' => float 27000
      3 => 
        array (size=4)
          'id' => string '111' (length=3)
          'nome' => string 'PROVALEIRA' (length=10)
          'qtd' => float 100
          'total' => float 6000
      4 => 
        array (size=4)
          'id' => string '110' (length=3)
          'nome' => string 'COOLERS' (length=7)
          'qtd' => float 84
          'total' => float 21000
      5 => 
        array (size=4)
          'id' => string '112' (length=3)
          'nome' => string 'CHAMPANHEIRA' (length=12)
          'qtd' => float 28
          'total' => float 1962.64
```

Bom como faço para ordenar ele pelo campo qtd, ou em ordem alfabética?

Estou montando o array assim:

```
while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta)) {

    // Array com dados do produto
    $curva[] = array(
        "id" => $resultado->id,
        "nome" => $resultado->nome,
        "qtd" => $qtd,
        "total" => $total
    );
}
```

Preciso pegar o array e mudar a ordem dele. Tem como fazer isso?

Comment: Poderia ter colocado a array em php ao invés de dump... pensa na trabalheira que o pessoal vai ter pra testar :(

Comment: Ia exatamente dizer isso @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Bom desculpa, e que estou lendo tudo do BD, vou editar a pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para ordenar você pode usar `uasort` para poder com um callback navegar pelo conteúdo de cada array, o primeiro parâmetro será o item atual e o segundo será o próximo, então você faz o comparativo e retorna `true` ou `false`.

Para ordenar de A-Z (alfabético) é necessário usar `strcmp`

### Ordena pela quantidade:

```
<?php
$teste = array(
    array(
        'id' => '107',
        'nome' => 'LAREIRA PEQ.',
        'qtd' => 43,
        'total' => 64500
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '108',
        'nome' => 'CHORAQUERIA PEQ.',
        'qtd' => 60,
        'total' => 48000
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '109',
        'nome' => 'JOGO DE FACAS',
        'qtd' => 90,
        'total' => 27000
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '111',
        'nome' => 'PROVALEIRA',
        'qtd' => 100,
        'total' => 6000
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '110',
        'nome' => 'COOLERS',
        'qtd' => 84,
        'total' => 21000
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '112',
        'nome' => 'CHAMPANHEIRA',
        'qtd' => 28,
        'total' => 1962.64
    )
);

uasort($teste, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['qtd'] < $b['qtd'];
    //Se quiser inverter a ordem basta trocar por return $a['qtd'] > $b['qtd'];
});

print_r($teste);
```

### Ordena pelo nome:

```
<?php
$teste = array(
    array(
        'id' => '107',
        'nome' => 'LAREIRA PEQ.',
        'qtd' => 43,
        'total' => 64500
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '108',
        'nome' => 'CHORAQUERIA PEQ.',
        'qtd' => 60,
        'total' => 48000
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '109',
        'nome' => 'JOGO DE FACAS',
        'qtd' => 90,
        'total' => 27000
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '111',
        'nome' => 'PROVALEIRA',
        'qtd' => 100,
        'total' => 6000
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '110',
        'nome' => 'COOLERS',
        'qtd' => 84,
        'total' => 21000
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '112',
        'nome' => 'CHAMPANHEIRA',
        'qtd' => 28,
        'total' => 1962.64
    )
);

uasort($teste, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['nome'], $b['nome']);
    //Se quiser inverter a ordem basta trocar por return strcmp($b['nome'], $a['nome']);
});

print_r($teste);
```

Comment: Parabéns pela ótima resposta. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @HugoBorges se quiser decrescente troque `$a['qtd'] < $b['qtd']` por `$a['qtd'] > $b['qtd']` e `strcmp($a['nome'], $b['nome'])` por `strcmp($b['nome'], $a['nome'])`

Comment: Blz eu já tinha testado isso hahahaha. Bom tenho mais uma dívida, de como escrever esse array usando o `foreach`, mais isso vai ser uma pergunta nova

Comment: @HugoBorges manda o link que respondo.

Comment: ok http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188479/como-dar-um-echo-no-array-usando-o-foreach