# como dar um echo no array usando o foreach

Tags: php

Bom tenho um variável `$curva` que contei um `array`, se eu ser um `var_dump` o resultado é esse:

```
 array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '107' (length=3)
      'nome' => string 'LAREIRA PEQ.' (length=12)
      'qtd' => float 43
      'total' => float 64500
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '108' (length=3)
      'nome' => string 'CHORAQUERIA PEQ.' (length=16)
      'qtd' => float 60
      'total' => float 48000
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '109' (length=3)
      'nome' => string 'JOGO DE FACAS' (length=13)
      'qtd' => float 90
      'total' => float 27000
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '111' (length=3)
      'nome' => string 'PROVALEIRA' (length=10)
      'qtd' => float 100
      'total' => float 6000
  4 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '110' (length=3)
      'nome' => string 'COOLERS' (length=7)
      'qtd' => float 84
      'total' => float 21000
  5 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string '112' (length=3)
      'nome' => string 'CHAMPANHEIRA' (length=12)
      'qtd' => float 28
      'total' => float 1962.64
```

Eu tentei fazer assim:

```
foreach ($curva as $c) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $c->id ?></td>
            <td><?= $c->nome ?></td>
            <td><?= $c->qtd ?></td>
            <td><?= $c->total ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
```

Mas não esta dando certo. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: `<td><?= $c['id'] ?></td>` funciona?

Comment: prefeito deu certo aqui, obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `->` é usado por `stdClass` e classe normais, não por arrays, em array usamos `array[chave]`, deve ficar assim:

```
<tr>
    <td><?= $c['id'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $c['nome'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $c['qtd'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $c['total'] ?></td>
</tr>
```

Uma dica para quando for misturar html e php, *mas é apenas opinião minha*, é usar a [**sintaxe alternativa**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) desta forma (mas somente quando misturar HTML e PHP, claro que vai de questão de gosto também):

```
<?php foreach ($curva as $c): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $c['id'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $c['nome'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $c['qtd'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $c['total'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

### Extra

Notei que no seu outro código você fez isso:

```
while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta)) {
    $curva[] = array(
        "id" => $resultado->id,
        "nome" => $resultado->nome,
        "qtd" => $qtd,
        "total" => $total
    );
}
```

Se você simplificar assim:

```
while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta)) {
    $curva[] = $resultado;
}
```

Vai ser possível usar isto:

```
<?php foreach ($curva as $c): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $c->id ?></td>
        <td><?= $c->nome ?></td>
        <td><?= $c->qtd ?></td>
        <td><?= $c->total ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

E a ordenação deve ficar assim ser for por `qtd`:

```
uasort($teste, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a->qtd < $b->qtd;
});
```

Se for por `nome`:

```
uasort($teste, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->nome, $b->nome);
});
```

Se quiser obter o índice atual pode fazer assim:

```
<?php foreach ($curva as $key => $c): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>Índice: <?= $key ?></td>
        <td><?= $c->id ?></td>
        <td><?= $c->nome ?></td>
        <td><?= $c->qtd ?></td>
        <td><?= $c->total ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Se quiser usar o indice para atualizar você pode pensar em tentar usar **referencia** usando o `&` ("e" comercial):

> Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

```
<?php foreach ($curva as &$c): ?>
    <?php
        $c->nome = 'João';
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $c->id ?></td>
        <td><?= $c->nome ?></td>
        <td><?= $c->qtd ?></td>
        <td><?= $c->total ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php

print_r($curva); //Veja que o valor foi atualizado

?>
```

Comment: prefeito deu certo aqui, obrigado

Comment: Legal, obrigado.

Comment: Só mais uma dívida, como recupero o índice? Preciso atualizar um campo específico.

Comment: O `índice`. Par atualizar eu faço assim `$curva[0]['nome'] = 'CD de Musica';`Preciso saber o índice para poder atualizar o campo certo. Como eu obtenho ele a partir da variável `$c`?

Comment: Quero atualizar um campo do array, e preciso capturar o índice dele. Entendeu?

Comment: mas é isso mesmo, quero fazer dentro do `foreach` como eu pego os indices? No exemplo que eu coloquei com dump tenho 5 indices.

Comment: tentei assim `foreach ($curva as $c) {
    
    echo key($c);

}`não deu certo.

Comment: @HugoBorges atualizei a resposta, veja se entendeu como pegar a chave (indice) ou como usar referencias.

Comment: Isso mesmo, vlw pela Paciência hahahah.